# Problems with scrpage2 and tabu at new windows 10 installation

Tags: windows, tabu, scrpage2

before I can describe the problem I want to give a short outline:

I work remotely for a small company. I am in direct contact to the workers which work at the head office, but I have no access to the computers there. But because only new employees are working there, I was choosen to care for the current problem. So I am not able to reproduce the problem for myself and just try to give a solution how they get their systems to work.

Basically they upgraded all their computers from windows 7 pro to windows 10 pro. Afterwards they installed miktex und upgraded all packages. Now occured the first problem: Although it was running on the old Windows 7-environment, the files led to errors in the new environment. Apparently something with the scrpage2-package.
For this problem they found the solution to include
\RequirePackage{scrlfile}\ReplacePackage{scrpage2}{scrlayer-scrpage} into the files.

Now there is a new error, that says that there is a missing { at the \begin{tabu} (and we have a lot of tabus -> lots of errors).

I am really not understanding why the exchange of one package leads to an error in another one.

Maybe someone has some possible solutions to try, even without the possibility to reproduce the error.

Comment: Read the readme here: https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu Most likely the Windows 7 systems had an old MikTex installation and the new systems a new MikTeX installation leading to these kind of problems.

Comment: This sound as if nobody in your company kept track of the changes in latex and the various packages and that you didn't maintain and update your files regularly. And now after the new install you are hit by the full lot of changes from a number of years. scrpage2 has been declared obsolete, but if needed you could get it from ctan. tabu was abandoned nearly 10 years ago by its maintainer, and not it is broken in various places, so basically you should better avoid to use it.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Replacing all the tabus means tons of work. Any suggestions of another package to make nice tables and stuff? 
I wonder if there is a possibility to use a new table package and then just create your own tabu-environment based an this new package, so that all the existing tabu-environments are just redefined with functions of the new package.